# How to prevent looking for DOM elements after window.location.href (redirection)

Tags: javascript, dom

In the ***index.html*** page I have the following code

```
  <body>
    <h1>First page</h1>
    <button id="submitBtn">Submit</button>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
```

The JS is a simple script that redirects the page to another page - ***second.html***

```
document.getElementById('submitBtn').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  window.location.href = 'another_file.html';
})
```

Once the second page is loaded, the console gives - ***TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'addEventListener')***. This is understandable as the next page doesn't have the ***submitBtn***.

How can I avoid this error?

Thanks

Comment: Is the second page running this same exact JavaScript code, or different code?  If it's running this same code... why?

Comment: @david Yes, I had the same file. I now understand the mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if it exists before attaching events to it.

```js
var elem = document.getElementById('submitBtn');
elem && elem.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  window.location.href = 'another_file.html';
})
```

As for your design decision the way I would structure it indeed use `script.js` for all the functions and the only difference is between the pages which own has a minimal `<script>` tag to initialize and insatiate its own stuff.

So for this instance, while both share the same `script.js`, only `index.html` page would include this snippet of code inside of it. and `second.html` should not bother at all with checking for that element.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have this in the "another_file.html"?

```
<script src="script.js"></script>
```

Because if you do, this is causing the issue.